# unboundLocalError - variable is key within dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def create_school(school,year):
    all_students = {}
    achievements= {}
    var = data.Files.get(school,year)
    for child in var.student_info_parsed:
        for gchild in var.student_info_parsed[child]:
            for ggchild in var.student_info_parsed[child][gchild]:
                all_students[ggchild[0]] = ggchild
    for child in var.student_info:
        for gchild in var.student_info[child]:
            if gchild == 'localidentifier':
                student = var.student_info[child][gchild]
                achievements[student] = {}
                achievements[student]['certificates'] = []
                achievements[student]['otherachievements'] = []
            if gchild == 'certificates':
                for ggchild in var.student_info[child][gchild]:
                    cert = var.student_info[child][gchild][ggchild]
                    cert_year = cert[2][0:4]
                    if cert_year == year:
                        achievements[student]['certificates'].append(cert)
            if gchild == 'otherachievements':
                ocert = var.student_info[child][gchild]
                n = 0
                while n < len(ocert):
                    ocert_year = ocert[n][1]
                    if ocert_year == year:
                        achievements[student]['otherachievements'].append(ocert[n])
                    n = n+1
            if gchild == 'endorsements':
                ecert = var.student_info[child][gchild]
                l = list()
                for subj in ecert:
                    if ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult'] != 'NO':
                        result = ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult']
                        l.append([subj,result]) 
                achievements[student]['endorsements'] = l
    return achievements
```

so before I added the condition

```
if gchild == 'endorsements':
    ecert = var.student_info[child][gchild]
    l = list()
    for subj in ecert:
        if ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult'] != 'NO':
        result = ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult']
            l.append([subj,result]) 
    achievements[student]['endorsements'] = l
```

everything was going find but now I'm getting error

```
  File "/Users/Teacher/Documents/Python/Standards/Data_Manipulation_3/data_man.py", line 454, in create_school
    achievements[student]['endorsements'] = l
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'student' referenced before assignment
```

whats weird to me is I have been referencing "student" fine up to this point.

I don't have a global variable named student?

I'm really confused I thought these errors happened when there was confusion between global and local variables but the "student" variable is just local?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `student` is created in the block preceded by `if gchild == 'localidentifier'`. If that block is executed, the variable `student` will be available. However, if the block preceded by `if gchild == 'endorsements'` is executed *before* the other block (because `gchild=='endorsements'` in an earlier iteration than `gchild=='localidentifier'`), then the variable `student` will not have been created.

Comment: Yeah this is the reason, looking back. when iterating through gchild, 'certificates' and 'otherachievements' come after 'localidentifier' but endoresments comes before so the student hasn't been created yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `gchild == 'endorsements'` and `gchild == 'localidentifier'` are exclusive - so there won't be a situation when both blocks of code will run. You are assigning value to `student` only in `if gchild == 'localidentifier':` block, so if the first `gchild` value is `'endorsements'` - the `student` won't be populated and you end up with UnboundLocalError.

I don't know specifics of your code, but I guess that you may want to populate the `student` var with value similar to first `if` block like this:

```
student = var.student_info[child][gchild]
```

Or you may use the `ecert` variable, which seems to hold the same value as `student` would:

```
if gchild == 'endorsements':
  ecert = var.student_info[child][gchild]
  l = list()
  for subj in ecert:
    if ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult'] != 'NO':
    result = ecert[subj]['courseendorsementresult']
        l.append([subj,result]) 
  achievements[ecert]['endorsements'] = l
```

Answer (score 0):

As you defined the `student` in following condition :

```
if gchild == 'localidentifier':
      student = var.student_info[child][gchild]
```

So under your second statement `if gchild == 'endorsements':` you dont define the `student`.as your conditions both check the value of `gchild` if one happen other doesn't ! so you have 2 choice

1. define the student in new statement too .
2. define it in top of the all conditions if its possible .